# Trying to take a photo from camera in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

I'm trying to take a photo with the phone camera and set the photo to an imageview in my layout.  I'm  new to android and I've done research but can find nothing conclusive.

When I run the app and hit the camera button I get this error in my logcat:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.IMAGE_CAPTURE }

Here's part of my code which has the camera intent:

```
public class PicOfDay extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
public ImageView picOfDay;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pic_of_day, container, false);
    picOfDay.setOnClickListener(this);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}

private void takePhoto() {
    Intent camIntent = new Intent("android.provider.MediaStore.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(camIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        picOfDay.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_picofday, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.camera) {
        takePhoto();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error may be caused by you using

"IMAGE_CAPTURE" instead of "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" Try using this instead:

```
        Intent camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Also (android.provider.MediaStore.Action_IMAGE_CAPTURE); should not be in quotes. See [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)
for details.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Definitely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

The Intent action is wrong: should be `"android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"` or as @Keylwin said, `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` (without quotes due is a Constant Value) for straightforward compatibilitiy.

please read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

```
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); // "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"
    startActivityForResult(camIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```